# OpenGL app error caused by bbutil.c

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, blackberry-10

Hi I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/good_citizen_overview_new_2006631_11.html) to draw a cube. I am using bbutil.h and bbutil.c files from [this](https://github.com/blackberry/NDK-Samples/tree/master/GoodCitizen) source. But I am always getting

`error bbutil must be compiled with either USING_GL11 or USING_GL20 flags`

My GoodCitizen.pro file is like this,

```
APP_NAME = GoodCitizen

 CONFIG += qt warn_on cascades10
 LIBS   += -lpps -lscreen -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lfreetype -lpng  -lbb
 #LIBS   += -lpps -lscreen -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lfreetype -lpng  -lbb -lQtCascades -    lheimdall ${QNX_TARGET}/../target-override/armle-v7/usr/lib/libQtCascades_main.a
 CCFLAGS+=-DUSING_GL11
 include(config.pri)
```

I dont know what to fix to remove that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem.

I didnt use 
`#define USING_GL11`

under the inclusions in bbutil.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a compiler option -DUSING_GL11 to solve this problem.

An easy way to do this is open the properties of the project then select C/C++ Build->Settings->QCC Compiler->Preprocessor and then add USING_GL11 to the Defines panel.

[image]